# Is there a way to trigger useState hook when the newvalue is same as oldvalue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I Have an animation to trigger when `selectedName` changes, but it seems is the newvalue is same as previous value the animation does not trigger. After looking into it, the hook only trigger is newvalue is different than previous value. Is there a way to fix this?

```
    const [selectedName, setSelectedName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Change", selectedName)
  }, [selectedName]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactts-text-animation-using-react-transition-group-64gum?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: You could chnange it to an object `const [selectedName, setSelectedName] = useState({value: ""});`. You can set it like so: `setSelectedName({value: "somevalue"})`. That way even if you update it to the same exact object, `useEffect` will trigger.

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to trigger when **value** changes, or when there is some event that **may change** value, but not necessarily do that?

Comment: @codemonkey it did solve the question regarding hook to trigger. In my case I'm using react-transition-group. It seems the animation still doesnt trigger even after the changes

Comment: @Mr. Hedgehog  No I want the hook to trigger even tho newvalue is same as previous value

Comment: Got it. So the animation probably is unrelated to the question at hand. If you can Sandbox your app (at least the basic version), I have zero doubt we can figure it out.

Comment: In this case you can either use solution given  by  @codemonkey, or use another state value that you will update (for example simple  number `let [updater, setUpdater] = useState(0); function triggerRender() {setUpdater(num  => num+1)}`

Comment: The effect does not trigger because the React virtual DOM does not update if the value stays same. If you want to use hooks, you care about simple things. For all other things, use class components, extend to pure if and when needed.

Comment: @codemonkey I updated the question with codesandbox link using randomnumbers. When you click the button. You can get a value of 1 or 2. If you get the same value twice you dont the the fading animation. I want the fading animation to occur even if the number hasnt changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea you had was correct - trigger a re-render on each click even if the number is the same. The only thing you did wrong was assign the same `key` prop to your `CSSTransition` element on each render of an identical element.

The key needs to be unique because React uses the key prop to understand the component-to-DOM Element relation, which is then used for the [reconciliation process](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). It is therefore very important that the key always remains unique, otherwise there is a good chance React will mix up the elements and mutate the incorrect one.

Anyway, you do need that second state variable to trigger a rerender. We will do something as basic as: `const [trigger, triggerUpdate] = useState<boolean>(false);`. You can then tigger it like so: `triggerUpdate(!trigger);`

And the most important part, of course, is the `key` prop

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SwitchTransition mode="out-in">
        <CSSTransition<undefined>
          classNames="fade"
          addEndListener={(node: HTMLElement, done: () => void) => {
            node.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false);
          }}
          key={Math.random()
            .toString(36)
            .replace(/[^a-z]+/g, "")}
        >
          <h1 className="randomNumberText">{rndNumber}</h1>
        </CSSTransition>
      </SwitchTransition>
      <button onClick={() => getRandomNumber()}>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Notice that I use this mechanism to come up with a unique `key`, you don't have to follow this example necessarily:

```
key={Math.random()
            .toString(36)
            .replace(/[^a-z]+/g, "")}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactts-text-animation-using-react-transition-group-forked-v2cm4?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thanks so much. I understand. Is it more safe to use  `new Date().toISOString() as key prop`? I assume that the key wont repeat in that case. How will this effect the react DOM or memory usage. Is there a way to destroy the previous one, maybe react handles this automatically? I dont fully understand the boolean triggered part. You change the value from true to false and vice versa everytime the `getRandomNumber` method runs. But I dont see it being used in the `CSSTransistion` component, how does it know when to update?

Comment: @CookieMonster I would just use `key={Date.now()}`

Comment: The `trigger` variable doesn't need to be used in the `return` method. Just updating it will trigger a re-render by itself and that's what we want.

Comment: Aha, so basically `CSSTransition` is looking for any changes in `getRandomNumber()` method to trigger the animation? It seems a bit confusing cause the button is the one calling the method and `button` component outside of `CSSTransition Component`.

Comment: @CookieMonster Well not exactly. It's not that `CSSTransition` is looking for any changes in anything, really. The point is that whenever you update ANY state variable, the `render` function will run again. Since `CSSTransition` is inside it, it will be rendered each time. So by creating this `trigger` variable we simply force `render` to run again. And when we do so, we make to make sure that `CSSTransition` has a unique `key` prop each time.

Comment: I see, I am using `const [rndNumber, setRndNumber] = useState({rnd: 0})` as you mentioned, It seems to get the job done and don't need to create boolean to re-render.